# Error getting 'canvas1' property when created by document.createElement('canvas1')

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a progress bar that is to operate while a map is generated in a game.  Here is the problem code snippet:

COREHTML5.RoundedRectangle.prototype = {

```
createCanvas: function () {
    var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas1");
    this.context1 = canvas1.getContext;
    return canvas1;
},
createDOMElement: function () {
    this.domElement = document.createElement("div");
    this.domElement.appendChild(this.context1.canvas1);
},
```

I get the error:  JavaScript Runtime Error: unable to get property 'canvas1' of undefined or null reference. This error happens in the last line of the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error: JavaScript Runtime Error: unable to get property
>   'canvas1' of undefined or null reference. This error happens in the
>   last line of the code snippet.

replace

```
 var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas1");
```

with

```
 var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");//observe that '1' is removed
```

since `canvas1` is not a valid html element

complete example could be

```
function a(){}
a.prototype.createCanvas =  function () {
    var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.context1 = canvas1.getContext;
    return canvas1;
}
a.prototype.createDOMElement =  function () {
    this.domElement = document.createElement("div"); 
    this.domElement.appendChild(this.context1.canvas1);
}
```

make sure that you add div to the DOM first before doing `appendChild` to it.